# After adding assembly references to a project, error occurs in all codes on Window.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I was developing WPF Application, and i want to use FolderBrowserDialog, so i was about to add [System.Windows.Forms.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHeHq.png).

Before Adding [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHeHq.png), there was no error.

[(this is picture before addition of reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC2cC.png)

But, after i added [System.Windows.Forms.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHeHq.png), Errors occurred in

Methods from partial classes, Components like Buttons, Labels in MainWindow.xaml.

[MainWindow.xaml.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjZyX.png)

How can I add reference assembly without errors?

Comment: Do you also get this error when you compile your project?

Comment: You coukd take a look at https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=openfolderdialog

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, it keeps failing to build.

Comment: Show us your "using" statements in the MainWindow.xaml.cs and all the "xmlns" statements from your MainWindow.xaml.  Perhaps there is a conflict there once you add the System.Windows.Forms reference.  Also, post the errors that occurred, so that helpers can get a better idea of what might be wrong.